# Cython problem, can't use cdef on class variables

Tags: python, c, python-3.x, cython, cythonize

I'm trying to convert a python class to C for time-complexity improvement using Cython. My most used variables are the class variables defined in the **init** method and therefore I would like to define them as cdef double. I have tried everything I can find but nothing let's me convert the code. It seems as if this should be the way to do it:

```
class Wall(object):

cdef double min_x, max_x, a, b, c

def __init__(self, start, stop):
    self.min_x = min(start[0], stop[0])
    self.max_x = max(start[0], stop[0])
    self.a = (stop[1]-start[1])/(stop[0]-start[0])
    self.b = -1
    self.c = start[1]-self.a*start[0]
```

But I get the following error:

> ```
> Error compiling Cython file:
> ------------------------------------------------------------
> ...
>
> class Wall(object):
>
>     cdef double min_x, max_x, a, b, c
>         ^
> ------------------------------------------------------------
>
> wall_class_cy.pyx:9:9: cdef statement not allowed here
> ```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I vote to close this as a typo, because it should be `cdef class Wall`, i.e. `cdef` was forgotten.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make the class variables public and provide a C declaration for the class as well. Try this:

```
cdef class Wall(object):

    cdef public double min_x, max_x, a, b, c

    def __init__(self, start, loop):
        ...
```